# Change the format of a number to readable in currency format?

Tags: java, android

In my application, i want to be able to:

make this number **300000** appear like this **300,000 USD** ?
I don't want it to be necessarily "**USD**" ,

I want to be able to choose my **own** currency too.

Comment: NumberFormat but the app is force closing. I tried getInstance(), getCurrencyInstance(), I also tried DecimalFormat but the app was also force closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you described, try counting every 3 digits (chars) from the end of a String that is the number and add a `','`. Then, at the end, add " USD" (space makes it look nicer).

Example code:

```
int toFormat = 1563992;
String output = "" + toFormat;
int counter = 0;
for (int index = output.length() - 1; index > 0; index--){
    counter++;
    if (counter % 3 == 0){
        counter = 0;
        output = output.subString(0,index) + "," + output.subString(index);
    }
}

output += " USD"; // or whatever you want
System.out.println(output);
```

outputs: `1,563,992 USD`

Comment: Thank you very much for this example. I thought there was already a finished class in java this is why i asked the question. Thank you :)

Comment: @JonathanHugh See this for another method: [Using Predefined Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html). Also, you can accept my answer if you liked it so much

Comment: you helped a lot!Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just append "USD" or whatever with the integer. 
like

```
int cash = 100;
    String currency="USD";
    String my_cash=String.valueOf(cash)+currency;
```